# SE FONT SCALING: stylebot: sidebar cover comments

Tags: google-chrome, css

[image: image of sidebar covering comments]

Mousing over a link in the sidebar works; therefore the sidebar is on top.

### Issue description

Commends ending under the sidebar cannot be deleted.

### What I've tried

**Workaround:** using Stylebot to set a user-side CSS rule:

```
td.comment-text {
    width: 500px;
}
```

### Question

My attempts to target have failed.  Would someone help me find the right target and rule?

### !Additional info

This is not *necessarily* a stackexchange bug.  I use font scaling because it prevents horizontal scrolling, which is very inconvenient for low-vision users.

### UPDATE/Resolution

```
tr td textarea{
  width: 475px;
}
```

Comment: What are the steps that you have reproduced the overlapping issue?

Comment: Can you post your alternate stylesheet CSS? How are you setting font scaling? Would be interesting to recreate this.

Comment: Rather than trying to edit another answer, or editing your solution into your question (or answering your meta question on this subject), if the answer doesn't work exactly, you should leave your own answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the default styles have a rule like this:

```
.comments {
  width: 660px;
}
```

Maybe try overriding that?

```
.comments {
  width: 500px;
}
```

### Update

The comments textarea specifies a `cols` attribute that makes it too wide, as well. This should shrink it down.

```
.comment-form textarea{
  width: 475px;
}
```

Comment: I don't see the suggested edit, but my rep might not be high enough. Try it again, or tell me what needs to be changed?

Comment: Hi!  I'm happy because now I can delete comments that are obsolete.  Thanks!  Okay: basically, I added the answer to the question.  `tr td textarea` as a target, with your rule, works. ^^  Peace!